# Fatou's lemma - Royden's proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Royden states that to prove Fatou's lemma it is ncessary and sufficent to show that if $h$ is any bounded measurable function of finite support for which  $0\leq h\leq f$ on $E$, then
$$
\int
_E h\leq \lim \inf \int_E f_n$$

Why did Royden choose to construct such a function instead of working directly with $f$?

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $\int f$ is the supremum of $\int h$ for $0 \leq h \leq f$ bounded measurable of finite support. So at the very end, you just need to take the sup over such $h$ to get $\int f \leq \liminf \int f_n$. He uses such $h$ is order to apply the *bounded* dominated convergence theorem, which he proves earlier. This allows him to prove Fatou in terms of dominated convergence instead of giving a completely independent proof (and potentially repeating a bunch of work).

Comment: Thank you! Very insightful.

Comment: I just want to follow up on this a bit further. You are taking the supremum of the set of functions $h$ that are bounded by $f$ right?

Comment: Instead of taking the supremum over a uncountable set of functions, can we prove it by contradiction in the end by assuming $\int f>\lim \inf f_n$ and use $\int_E h\leq\lim \inf \int_E f_n$ to draw the conclusion. Because I am not sure how the supremum over a uncountable set of functions works.

Comment: While it would be possible to do it the way you suggest, I would highly encourage you to instead familiarize yourself with how to take the supremum of a set. This is, after all, the _definition_ of the integral. There is no need to search for a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

You can also let $g_n=inf_{i \geq n} \{f_n\}$ and note that $\int g_n \leq \int f_n$ for each n.  Moreover $g_n$ increases monotonically to lim inf $f_n$ . Hence by monotone convergence theorem $\int g_n = \int lim inf f_n$.  Since $\int g_n \leq \int f_n$ we have $\int lim inf f_n \leq lim inf \int f_n$.  The final step is to note that pointwise convergence implies lim inf $f_n$ = f